# How to use Scalaz's traverse and traverseU with Either

Tags: scala, scalaz

Is it possible to use Scalaz' `traverse` and `traverseU` with `Either` instead of `Option`?

For the following code:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)

def f(i: Int): Either[Int, String] =
  if (i > 2) Left(i)
  else Right("must be lower than 3")
```

I want to traverse `list` with `f` and either return the first `Right(msg)` if there is one or more failure, or `Left(list)` if everything went right.

Comment: Did you swap Left and Right on purpose? Usually Left is meant for handling failure.

Comment: @Dimitri No it wasn't on purpose at all! I'm coming from OCaml and am not yet used to Scala's conventions. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Right is the *right* one by convention, although scala.Either is quite symmetric (and it fact, a bit too much so, it is often inconvenient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any reason why you're not using `Validation` and `NonEmptyList` by scalaz?

You can easily do something like

```
def f(i: Int) =
  if (i > 2) i.successNel
  else "something wrong".failureNel

List(1, 2, 3).traverseU(f) // Failure(NonEmptyList(something wrong, something wrong))
List(3, 4, 5).traverseU(f) // Success(List(3, 4, 5))
```

If you instead want to fail on the first error, you can use `\/`, aka the scalaz version of `Either` which is isomorphic to `scala.Either` but right-biased

```
def f(i: Int) =
  if (i > 2) \/-(i)
  else -\/("something wrong")

List(1, 2, 3).traverseU(f) // Failure(something wrong)
List(3, 4, 5).traverseU(f) // Success(List(3, 4, 5))
```