# Access both the success and the failure from an aggregated ValidationNel

Tags: scala, scalaz

Is it possible to use a ValidationNel to return a mixture of both errors and successes?

So given the example:

```
def f(i: Int) =
  if (i > 2) i.successNel
  else "something wrong".failureNel

List(1, 2, 3).traverseU(f) // Failure(NonEmptyList(something wrong, something wrong))
```

Borrowed from [How to use Scalaz's traverse and traverseU with Either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510386) we get two failures (1,2) and a success (3). As we have more than 0 failures the result is a failure but is there any way to access the success from 3 or is that just thrown away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Look at [@melps answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32824369/5020846) for `separate` from [`MonadPlus`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.MonadPlus).

---

You use `Validation[E, X]` and thus also `ValidationNel[E, X]` for error accumulation, compared with `Try`, `Either` or scalaz's disjunction `\/` which fail fast and only give you the first failure.

The `traverse` function is a combination of `map` and `sequence`.

```
List(1, 2, 3).map(f).sequenceU == List(1, 2, 3).traverseU(f)
```

If we look at the intermediate result after map :

```
List(1, 2, 3).map(f)
// List[scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],Int]] = 
// List(Failure(NonEmptyList(something wrong)), 
//   Failure(NonEmptyList(something wrong)), 
//   Success(3))
```

We can see our intermediate result is of type `Validation[NonEmptyList[String], Int]]`, which is equal to `ValidationNel[String, Int]`.

If we then look at the last step (`sequence`) :

- `sequence` is a function to turn a monad inside out (`F[G[_]] => G[F[_]]`), in this case we go from `List[ValidationNel[String, Int]]` to `ValidationNel[String, List[Int]]`.
- The context of `Validation` is that we want to know if our function succeeded or not and in case of failure to accumulate all the errors.

As a consequence by using `sequence` we lose the information about which elements of our list succeeded.

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness - if you *really* wanted to collect all the results - you could do
`val res0 = List(1,2,3).map(f) ` and then

`
res0.foldMap(_.fold({e => (e.toList -> List())}, {s => (List() -> List(s))}))
`

this converting each validation into a tuple of List values and then using an implicit Monoid to append all the lists together resulting in 

`
(List(something wrong, something wrong),List(3))
`

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to get both the success and failures, a much cleaner way is to use `.separate`

```
import scalaz.syntax.validation._
import scalaz.syntax.monadPlus._
import scalaz.std.list._

@ val a = "yeah".success[Int]
a: Validation[Int, String] = Success(yeah)
@ val b = "wot".success[Int]
b: Validation[Int, String] = Success(wot)
@ val c = 10.failure[String]
c: Validation[Int, String] = Failure(10)
@ List(a,b,c).separate
res6: (List[Int], List[String]) = (List(10), List("yeah", "wot"))
```

Comment: that looks great, and works when using the example you have supplied but when I use it with a real world example, with success being a class , I get : could not find implicit value for parameter G: scalaz.Bifoldable[G] . I presume I have to create an implcit for the class that I am using but am a little unsure of how.

Comment: ```def separate[G[_, _], A, B](value: F[G[A, B]])(implicit G: Bifoldable[G]): (F[A], F[B]) ```  Looking at the signature, the Bifoldable instance is needed for G which in this case is Validation, which must already exist. Perhaps check your imports?

Comment: When you write "perhaps check your imports" could you please be more specific on what to check, and perhaps update your answer with working imports?

Comment: Specifically you need to make sure you have an implicit instance of Bifoldable avaliable for the structure you are trying to separate. In this instance it is for Validation which appears to be automatically brought into scope, but if it were some custom class you would need to provide an instance yourself.